# How to filter related data using Entity Framework and LINQ to SQL and LinqKit PredicateBuilder Or IdeaBlade DevForce

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, predicatebuilder, devforce

I am using Entity Framework 6.1.0 and LINQ to SQL

My object graph:

Market 1...n MarketAsset n...n CompanyMarket n...1 Company

So,

```
Market has a Collection of MarketAsset called MarketAssets
MarketAsset has a collection of CompanyMarket called CompanyMarkets
CompanyMarket has a property name callled Company
Company has a string property called Guid.
```

My question is: How do I get a list of all markets that a Company operates, considering that I need to filter the Company.Guid property?

PS1: I want to return ONLY the Markets. I do not want to include any other related entity into my result set.

PS2: I am using IdeaBlade DevForce as well.

Thank you in advance.

Best whishes,
Marco Alves.

Comment: To be honest, I really don't know from where to start with. I'm sorry if this isn't what you're expecting. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: IdeaBlade DevForce through me - is that important to the question? It looks like very few people are familiar with DevForce. If its not important, you may want to remove it from the title and the tags.

Answer (score 1):

This is ugly, but should work for your case. EF should translate this into a relatively efficient query.

```
        db.Markets.Where(mrkt =>
            mrkt.MarketAssets.Any(ma =>
                ma.CompanyMartkets.Any(cm =>
                    cm.Company.Guid == yourFilterGuid))).ToList();
```

Comment: I know I haven't mentioned. But is it possible to do it via PredicateBuilder or IdeaBlade DevForce?

Answer (score 0):

In DevForce try this

```
  var query = mgr.Companies.Where(comp => comp.Guid.Equals(searchGuid))
    .SelectMany(comp => comp.CompanyMarkets)
    .SelectMany(cMkt => cMkt.MarketAssets)
    .Select(mAsset => mAsset.Market);

  var results = await query.ExecuteAsync();

  results = results.Distinct();
```

If you want to use DevForce's PredicateBuilder, the code would look like this:

```
  var p1 = PredicateBuilder.Make(typeof(Company), "Guid", FilterOperator.IsEqualTo, searchGuid);
  var selector1 = new ProjectionSelector("CompanyMarkets");
  var selector2 = new ProjectionSelector("MarketAssets");
  var selector3 = new ProjectionSelector("Market");

  var rootQuery = EntityQuery.Create(typeof(Company), mgr2);

  var dynamicQuery = rootQuery
    .Where(p1)
    .SelectMany(selector1)
    .SelectMany(selector2)
    .Select(selector3);
```

I suggest checking DevForce's documentation at http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/dynamic-queries for more information on dynamic querying.

Comment: Thank yoy @sbelini. What if I dont know the entities at compile time, i.e., I want to build it dynamically, using PredicateBuilder??

Comment: Note the method EntityQuery.Create(). There I hardcoded the EntityType Company, but it could have been any other EntityType.